# Converting information from string to dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, text

I have a string like this:

```
COLUMN 1:
    A:                         10.68
    B:                         11.82
    C:                         12.93
    D:                         50.2
C 2:
    Z:                         68
    S:                         182
    W:                         13
    E:                         50
```

What is a good way to preserve this information in a data structure like a dictionary?

UPDATE: The problem is, the headers don't necessarily start with COLUMN in my actual text, and the number of elements under each header could be different from the other. The only distinguishing element is that under each header, elements are indented with 4 spaces.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you give a concrete example of the string you want to convert?

Comment: A nested dict can be used like {1: {'A': 10.68, 'B': 11.82}, 2: {'Z': 68, 'S': 182}}. Access it like column[1]['A'].

Comment: @Tristan Yes, that seems a very useful structure.

Comment: @Tristan You should make this an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: [so] is not a code writing service. Please review [ask] and show us what you've tried to solve the issue.

Comment: @TemporalWolf I know I could split the text based on spaces, but there is an ambiguity with regards to distinguishing between a header and its elements. They are only different in the way they are indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired in [@Vor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1516286/vor)'s answer.

```
result, root = {}, None

for i in q.split('\n'):
    if i.strip().endswith(':'):
        root = i.strip()
        result[root] = {}
    elif i:
        val = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), i.split(':')))
        result[root].update({val[0]: val[1]})

print(result)
```

Following the rules:

- Headers ends with `:`
- Items delimiter is `:`
- No empty lines

The change is that you could store each root key, `Column X` in a var, and check all lines above this root key, and iterate and update this key.

Answer (score 0):

You can create nested dict like this:

```
q = '''
COLUMN 1:
    A:                         10.68
    B:                         11.82
    C:                         12.93
    d:                         50.2
COLUMN 2:
    Z:                         68
    S:                         182
    W:                         13
    E:                         50
'''

result = {}
for line in q.split('\n'):
  if line.strip() and not line[0].isspace():
      col = line.strip()[:-1]
      result[col] = {}
  elif line.strip():
      key, value = line.split(':')
      result[col][key.strip()] = value.strip()

print result
```

result:

```
{'COLUMN 2': {'S': '182', 'Z': '68', 'E': '50', 'W': '13'}, 'COLUMN 1': {'A': '10.68', 'C': '12.93', 'B': '11.82', 'd': '50.2'}}
```

Alternatively if order matters, you can make `COLUMN x` - lists and append items there in order

Comment: I don't want the algorithm to be dependent on the keyword COLUMN

Comment: Then split it by `:` and check if value is `""` - this would be your `COLUMN`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I didn't clearly explain. Please see the updated question.

Comment: If you don't like above splitting  approach, then check if `line.strip() and line[0].isspace()`

Comment: `key, value = line.split(':')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
`

Answer (score 0):

similar with slight tweak:

```
res = {}
for row in data.split('\n'):
    if row[:4] != '    ':
        res[row.strip(':')] = sub = {}
    else:
        k,v = row.split(':')
        sub[k.strip()] =v.strip()

print res
```

Output is:

```
{'C 2': {'S': '182', 'Z': '68', 'E': '50', 'W': '13'}, 'COLUMN 1': {'A': '10.68', 'C': '12.93', 'B': '11.82', 'D': '50.2'}}
```

If order matters, use ordered_dict instead

Comment: Please edit your answer to make it work for Python3. This code only works in Python2.x. See my last comment under Vor's answer.